# how to use the eventual lauching console in a winmain application?

Tags: user-interface, winapi, console, winmain

I have a small winmain application.
It is a winmain because I don't want it to flash a console at startup.
But if it is launched from a console, I would like to print in this console.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes, via `AttachConsole`, but it will be better if you allocate a new one via `AllocConsole`. The console application that started your program probably isn't waiting for your process to exit, so if you attach to its console and print, then you'll probably be injecting text into the middle of user input or mixed in with its output.

Comment: I will only print at the startup of my app. So I am not worried about this console being used at the same time. How do I find this console to attach it ? thanks.

Comment: It's `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)`, as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole).

Comment: actually the attachconsole works, but it is not printing in it. I will try to attach the stdout as well.

Comment: Before calling `AttachConsole`, call `SetStdHandle` to set all 3 standard handles to `NULL`. This ensures they'll be updated with handle values for the console. For the CRT you'll have to close file descriptors 0,1,2 and call `_open_osfhandle` on each standard handle in order of standard input, output, and error. If you want `FILE` streams you can use `_fdopen`. Alternatively, if you want to use the `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` streams (e.g. for `wprintf`) , call `freopen` with the special "CONIN$" and "CONOUT$" device files instead of calling `_open_osfhandle` on the standard handles.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by eryksun in the comments, `AttachConsole` is not perfect because cmd.exe only waits for console applications.

A sneaky workaround is to have a little console helper .exe that you rename to .com. It sits between you and the parent console application. You still need to use `AttachConsole` or `DuplicateHandle` to get access to the console handles in the GUI application...

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution I've retained:

```
if ( AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS) )
{
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    int fd = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hStdOut, _O_TEXT);
    if (fd > 0) *stdout = *_fdopen(fd, "w");
}
```

Comment: Assigning to `*stdout` isn't portable, and I don't think it even works with the new Universal CRT, which uses C++ objects.